# Category of monoids isomorphic to coslice category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory, algebras, slice-category

Let $k$ be a commutative ring and $R$ a $k$-algebra. The category $R\text{-Bimod}$ of $R$-bimodules becomes a monoidal category with the tensor product of $R$-bimodules. Denote the category of $k$-modules by $k$-Mod. The category of monoid objects $\text{Mon}(R\text{-Bimod})$ is isomorphic to the undercategory $R/\text{Mon}(k\text{-Mod}).$ Similarly the category of commutative $k$-algebras is isomorphic to the coslice category of commutative rings under $k$. For another example where a category of monoids is isomorphic to a certain coslice category see Remark 5.5 [here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/38/26/38-26.pdf#page11).

*Question.*
Is there an abstract nonsense proof of the fact that these categories of monoids are isomorphic coslice categories? Are they all instances of a more general result? I can verify that these categories are isomorphic, but I would prefer a conceptual explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are instances of a more general result. The following appears as Proposition 10.2 in Lucyshyn-Wright's [Enriched algebraic theories and monads for a system of arities](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02920).

> **Proposition.** Given a monoid $K$ in a monoidal category $\mathscr C$ with reflexive coequalizers that are preserved by $\otimes$ in each variable, there is an isomorphism:
> $$\text{Mon}(\text{Bimod}_{\mathscr C}(K)) \cong K/\text{Mon}(\mathscr C)$$

In fact, there is an even more general result, in which we generalise from monoids in a monoidal category to monads in a double category. This appears as Theorem 2.3.18 in Spivak–Schultz–Rupel's [String diagrams for traced and compact categories are oriented 1-cobordisms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.01069), but I won't state it here since it requires some set up.

Unfortunately, I don't know of an entirely abstract proof of the statement, but it is fairly straightforward to verify at the level of generality of monoids in a monoidal category.